# Where can I find the German GAFOR online?

Tags: weather, germany

Where can I access the [GAFOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GAFOR) for Germany for free online (or at least something close)?

Answer (score 3):

You can find all the free aviation weather services of the DWD here:

https://www.dwd.de/DE/fachnutzer/luftfahrt/teaser/luftsportberichte/luftsportberichte_tabelle.html